# Is there a way to customize the ADFS response message for device-code flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs, adfs4.0

Product: ADFS 4.0

I have setup an application group to test "device code" flow using the reference from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios#device-code-flow and it is working.
I however want to customize the response coming from the ADFS, particularly this message (refer the highlighted part in image) and I couldn't find any way to do that.

Can anybody help with that ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not configurable currently. Please open a support case with Microsoft if you wish to provide feedback as to why you want this configurable.

I assume you don't want to parse the JSON and show your own message in the app as to what the user should do?

Comment: Is still the case? I wanted to customize this message to make display a short URL so users don't have to retype a long URL into a browser.